# Huge delay on first browser-request to mono-fastcgi-server4 with Nginx hosted web-application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nginx, mono, xsp, fastcgi-mono-server

We are using mono version 3.10.0 (from $mono --version) and Nginx (1.6.2) and mono-fastcgi-server4 to host a ASP.Net MVC3 web-application running on an Debian jessie linux (ARM - Raspberry Pi).

Basically we seem to have the same problems as described in this question:
[Huge delay on first browser-request to Mono XSP hosted web-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151835/huge-delay-on-first-browser-request-to-mono-xsp-hosted-web-application)

When the first request from a browser / website-visitor is made mono-fastcgi-server uses all CPU it can get for up to 120s seconds until the webpage is shown in the webbrowser. This happens after each start/restart of the webserver.

As I understood so far this is quite normal and even the same if your are hosting your website with IIS on a windows server. The main difference is that the Windows server is much faster...

To minimize the startup time this is what I already tried:

1. **Precompile my razor views** into dlls by using the "publish website" feature in Visual Studio. This works so far but seems not to reduce the startup-time significantly.
2. Next thing I came upon was **AOTing** (Ahead of time compiling) my dlls in the bin folder (see http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/runtime/docs/aot/) I used 'mono --aot file.dll` to precompile my assemblies. Again no performance boost.
3. Then I found out you can of course also **AOT all of the libraries on your system** (found here: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/aot/) by using these commands:

   ```
   mono --aot /usr/lib/mono/1.0/mscorlib.dll 
   for i in /usr/lib/mono/gac/*/*/*.dll; do mono --aot $i; done
   ```

   This took quite a long time on may raspberry but - again - the same result.

Am I doing something wrong or missing something obvious?

The author of the before mentioned question said in his last comment about the delay:

> Its caused by generating and compiling the razor views which can not
>   yet be pre-compiled. Those files get compiled into /tmp/... which is
>   mapped to memory on the embedded devices and therefore gets lost after
>   reboot. Even worst is that after each restart of the XSP webserver the
>   files will be compiled into a new subdirectory of /tmp. This way
>   re-compiling the razor views happen each time XSP is started.

I think it's 
It seems that it is the same with me regardless of using XSP4, mono-fastcgi-server and probably also mod-mono when using Apache. (What is not surprising as I think they are all based on XSP - but maybe I'm wrong...)

Now the question mentioned is from 2011...does anybody know if there is a solution to get the webserver to use these precompiled files?

I am thankful for any hint!

Comment: Same here with asp mvc4 and mono 3.12.1 ... did you solve this in the end?

Comment: No. The "solution" was to switch to node.js in the end. Works quite well...

Comment: Good to know, so you avoided asp.net completely, right?

Comment: Yes...and this was quite sad as we had setup a nice running system with Entitfy Framework and Postgresql. But we had to switch to another technology stack because of our customer's requirements.